# How to handle lifecycle signal with Behavior.receiveMessage

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

I have an actor, that is created as follows:

```
    Behaviors.setup { context =>
          val greeter = context.spawn(HelloWorld.greeter, "greeter")

          Behaviors.receiveMessage { message =>
            val replyTo = context.spawn(HelloWorldBot.bot(greetingCounter = 0, max = 3), message.name)
            greeter ! HelloWorld.Greet(message.name, replyTo)
            Behaviors.same
          }
        }
```

I would like to handle **Signals** messages(for example PostStop) within the `Behaviors.receiveMessage` and in the doc says:

> Simplified version of Receive with only a single argument - the
>   message to be handled. Useful for when the context is already
>   accessible by other means, like being wrapped in an setup or similar.
>   Construct an actor behavior that can react to both incoming messages
>   and lifecycle signals. After spawning this actor from another actor
>   (or as the guardian of an akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem) it will be
>   executed within an ActorContext that allows access to the system,
>   spawning and watching other actors, etc. Compared to using
>   AbstractBehavior this factory is a more functional style of defining
>   the Behavior. Processing the next message results in a new behavior
>   that can potentially be different from this one. State is maintained
>   by returning a new behavior that holds the new immutable state.

But how to implement the lifecycle Signals within the `Behaviors.receiveMessage`?

Here is the link to the doc https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/actor/typed/scaladsl/Behaviors$.html#receiveMessageT:akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors.Receive[T]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `receiveMessage[A]` can only match on messages that conform to type `A` and there is no way for you to declare a type `A` that includes the system messages for `PostStop`, etc. Instead Akka-Typed has a dedicated `receiveSignal`.

Given your example, where you are already capturing a shared context via `Behavior.setup`, you can chain `receiveSignal` onto the message behavior to be part of the same behavior:

```
Behaviors.setup { context =>
      val greeter = context.spawn(HelloWorld.greeter, "greeter")

      Behaviors.receiveMessage { message =>
        val replyTo = context.spawn(HelloWorldBot.bot(greetingCounter = 0, max = 3), message.name)
        greeter ! HelloWorld.Greet(message.name, replyTo)
        Behaviors.same
      }.receiveSignal {
         case (context, PostStop) =>
           context.log.info("behavior stopped")
           Behaviors.same
    }
```